# DB select where data exist

Tags: sql, database, select, where-clause

I need to retrieve a random ID of a user which has in another table the avatar field not empty

```
SELECT userid FROM table1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'avatar' FROM table2 WHERE avatar IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

This query returns a result incorrect also showing me who has no avatar

Comment: Which database are you using? Could you please publish the table structure for table1 and table2? If possible, the data as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume a table structure as follows:

```
table1 {
    userid primary key
    [...]
}

table2 {
    [...]
    userid foreign key
    avatar
}
```

The following SQL should work:

```
SELECT userid FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.userid = b.userid
WHERE avatar IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```